# In plotly, how do I create a linked X axis?

Tags: python, plotly

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.graph_objs import *

py.sign_in('uname', 'pass')


trace1 = Scatter(
    x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
    y=[24,25,30,21,33,31,30,29],
    mode='lines',
    xaxis='x1',
    )

layout = Layout(
    title="My first plot",
    yaxis=YAxis(
        title = "y1"
        ),
    xaxis=XAxis(
        title= 'x1',
        anchor = 'x2'
        ),
    xaxis2=XAxis(
        title= 'x2',
        side = 'top',
        overlaying = 'y'
        ),
    )

data = [trace1]

fig = Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

plot_url = py.plot(fig)
```

I am trying to create a second X axis on the top of the plot (let's call it x2). I want it to be linked to x1 values with a formula x2=x1*0.3. In matplotlib, I would simply define another axis and redefine its range, and the ratio would be maintained even if I zoom in/out:

```
ax2 = ax1.twiny()
start, end = ax1.get_xlim()
ax2.set_xlim(start*0.3, end*0.3)
```

So the effect should look like this: [image: Scaled axes in matplotlib]

How do I achieve the same effect in plotly?

Answer (score 3):

Pretty close! Here is a simple example of multiple x-axes in Plotly, adapted from [this example of multiple y-axes in Plotly with Python](https://plot.ly/python/multiple-axes/)

```
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.graph_objs import *

trace1 = Scatter(
    x=[1,2,3],
    y=[24,30,25],
    mode='lines',
    xaxis='x1',
)

trace2 = Scatter(
    x=[10,20,30],
    y=[24,25,30],
    mode='lines',
    xaxis='x2',
)

layout = Layout(
    title="Multiple X-Axes",
    yaxis=YAxis(
        title = "y1"
        ),
    xaxis=XAxis(
        title= 'x-axis 1'
    ),
    xaxis2=XAxis(
        title= 'x-axis 2',
        side = 'top',
        overlaying='x1'
    )
)

data = [trace1, trace2]

fig = Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

py.plot(fig, filename='multiple x axes')
```

Which creates this graph: [image: Graph with multiple x-axes] (Interactive version: https://plot.ly/~chris/3285)

Note that you can zoom and pan on the individual axes: [image: Interactivity of a Plotly graph with multiple x-axes]

You can specify the range of these axes manually, with the [`Range` parameter](https://plot.ly/python/reference#XAxis-range), which would maintain the ratio as you zoom in and out with scroll. Here is a simple example:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.graph_objs import *

trace1 = Scatter(
    x=[1,2,3],
    y=[24,30,25],
    mode='lines',
    xaxis='x1',
)

trace2 = Scatter(
    x=[10,20,30],
    y=[24,25,30],
    mode='lines',
    xaxis='x2',
)

layout = Layout(
    title="Multiple X-Axes",
    yaxis=YAxis(
        title = "y1"
        ),
    xaxis=XAxis(
        title= 'x-axis 1',
        range=[1, 3]
    ),
    xaxis2=XAxis(
        title= 'x-axis 2',
        side = 'top',
        overlaying='x1',
        range=[10, 30]
    )
)

data = [trace1, trace2]

fig = Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

py.plot(fig, filename='multiple x axes with custom range')
```

[And here is the graph](https://plot.ly/~chris/3286/)

Comment: @Chris_P Thanks for the reply, but you are using two traces. Is there a way to create two axes with different scaling if I only want to plot one trace?

Comment: Ohh, I see. No, each trace can only be linked to a single axis. So, you could create 2 traces with the same data and attach each trace do a different axis with a different range. Just curious, what's the motivation for 2 axes, single trace?

Comment: but even if I create 2 traces, the axes will not be linked (i.e. one will not zoom in when the other does). There are plenty of applications: two temperature scales (°C on one, °F on the other), spectroscopy (wavelength on one, wave number/energy on the other), my example (current on one, current density - which depends on the geometry of the sample - on the other), etc.

Comment: I see - Here is an example of 2 traces (different x-data, same y-data) on 2 x-axes: https://plot.ly/~chris/3289. They'll overlap as long as the x-data of one trace is just a linear transformation of the x-data on the other trace. Does that work?

Comment: not really, sorry. The point is that the axes should be "linked", i.e. one should pan/zoom when the other does, just like in the animation on the bottom of my question. It would be a nice feature to have in plotly.