# Q: Plotly.js Linking 2 X Axes

Tags: javascript, plotly

In Plotly.js I am trying to allow users to see two (related) values for positions on the x axis. (Think if I'm doing dates I want it to say "Tuesday" on the lower axis and June 28th 2016 on a linked axis) Linking the axes would preferably preserve the relation between values when scrolling or zooming.

I had a temporary solution in place, where I would change the values from floats (as that was what we were using) to strings with a break character intended to separate the values (which allowed viewing both values at once albeit on one axis), however when tested with floats that were not equally spaced the slope would change visually, which is not desired. Another solution I have tried was to have the ticks be their float values, and then change their values after they were plotted using the "tickvals" and "ticktext" attributes, but I was unable to then hide some tick text while keeping others view-able on the x axis (and with 80 values it became quite busy and unreadable) There is the solution of hiding all of these tick values, but I was hoping there would be a solution where I could see some of them.

I created an example of the problems I am having in jsbin, so I hope it is kosher to link to that. https://jsbin.com/buwuyid/1/edit?html,output (and also hope the link works.)

There was a similar question asked previously, [In plotly, how do I create a linked X axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27334585/in-plotly-how-do-i-create-a-linked-x-axis) however that was a year ago and using python, and I was hoping that an implementation that I cannot find has been found, or a solution to one of the other problems I have found could be provided.

Thank you for any help you can provide, and if I can include any more information to help find a solution, please ask.